# Android adding mipmap-xxxhdpi icon

Tags: android, drawable, android-drawable, mipmaps

[image: mipmap file color red]

I added a new version (mipmap-xxxhdpi) in my old project.
But the file is coming in red color and also one more file ic_launcher-web.png got generated.

Can you explain why this things happens and how resolve them?

Comment: This will happens when your project is connected to github repository.

Comment: Could you elaborate what version control tool are you using? (Git, svn, ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is red, it means it is not under version control (was not yet added).

You should **right click the file** > **Subversion / Git** > **Add to VCS**.

The **ic_launcher-web.png** one, is meant to be used for when you publish to Google Play, you can easily delete it for now.

Answer (score 0):

Your project is under source control (git?). Red files are files not added to the repository yet. To fix it you need to add file: `git add` in the console or similar command in the Android Studio GUI.

`ic_launcher-web.png` is icon with size 512x512. It should be used when you publish your app in the Play Store.

Answer (score 0):

**@adarsh :** Actually your project is connected to [github](https://github.com/) repository .

**`Red means the branch is behind its remote`**

**CLICK** `Click CNTRL+SHIPT+A` **ON THIS IMAGE**

You should add and comment like this way

```
  prompt> git add some-file
  prompt> git commit -m "Your Comments"
```

Or you can **Click VCS->GIT->PUSH**

**`ic_launcher-web.png`** This is the icon for the google play store. You need to provide a *512 x 512* icon. [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13895390/what-does-the-ic-launcher-web-png-in-my-project-root-do)